# Using express.static, path.join, res.sendFile to serve files

Tags: node.js, express

I have a React app + Node server with the following architecture from the root :

/build

/src

server.js

package.json

etc.

In production, I want to get to the index.html inside the folder "build", so I have this code in the server, but I think I did it wrong :

```
server.js

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build")));
  app.get("*", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "build", "index.html"));
  });
}
```

Can somebody help me ? Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the problem?   What doesn't work as desired?  Which exact URL doesn't do what you want it to?  And, what is it that you want it to do?  We need to know what incoming URL is supposed to serve what file that isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code, though I don't think there is a need to define a route `GET "*"`. When you serve public static files, they can be accessed directly through the browser.

For now, to debug your app:

1. Make sure that the "build" directory exists and actually contains an index.html
2. Log 'NODE_ENV' environment variable, just to make sure that it's set correctly to 'production'.

Comment: I can see log from the server in the terminal when I'm in development, but in production how can I see logs ?

Comment: @Versifiction what process manager are you using?! Also, do you use certain logging libraries? e.g: Winston

Comment: i'm using morgan, so I can see the logs in the terminal

Comment: @Versifiction then console.log(..) is your friend. add ``console.log(`NODE_ENV: ${process.env.NODE_ENV}`)`` just before the if statement.